Explicit translation of Ramanujan’s condition for the Selberg Class?
According to many sites such as Wikipedia, the Ramanujan condition of the Selberg class can be stated as
$$\boxed{\forall\epsilon>0:a_n\ll_\epsilon n^\epsilon}$$
My question is: what exactly does it mean? Is it simply that $$\forall\epsilon>0:a_n = O(n^\epsilon)\text{ as } n\to\infty$$
or does it mean another thing? I’m not very used to the notations $\ll_\epsilon$ and $O_\epsilon(\cdot)$. So, if you could translate it with “simple” terms, it would be quite helpul. For example, one could rewrite the latter expression in “simple” terms as
$$\forall\epsilon>0:\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{|a_n|}{n^\epsilon}<\infty$$
or, equivalently in this case (I think),
$$\forall\epsilon>0:\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|a_n|}{n^\epsilon}=0$$
so that $\forall\epsilon>0:a_n = o(n^\epsilon)\text{ as } n\to\infty$. Is this interpretation correct? Thanks!

I think $a_n\ll_\epsilon n^\epsilon$ means that  $$a_n \le C_\epsilon n^\epsilon$$
for sufficiently large $n$ where the constant $C_{\epsilon}$ depends only on $\epsilon$.
It can be written as
$$a_n=O_{\epsilon}(n^{\epsilon})$$
which means
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{|a_n|}{n^\epsilon}=C_{\epsilon}<\infty$$

So are the following statements equivalent?
$$1.\forall\epsilon>0:a_n\ll_\epsilon n^\epsilon$$
$$2. \forall\epsilon>0\ \exists C_\epsilon>0\ \forall n\geq1: |a_n|\leq C_\epsilon n^\epsilon$$
$$3. \forall\epsilon>0: a_n/n^\epsilon \to 0$$

The last two are equivalent since 2. for $\epsilon/2$ implies 3. for $\epsilon$ and 3. implies 2. by taking $C_\epsilon=\sup_n{|a_n|/n^\epsilon}$ which must be finite since convergent implies bounded. Right?

@tripaloski : I think you are right.
